# Kryo: How to use the CollectionSerializer with Scala?

Tags: scala, kryo

Using CollectionSerializer to write is straight forward enough, but how do I de-serialize the byte array. CollectionSerial.

I would expect to be able to do something like this (given the interface):

```
listSerializer.read(kryo, new Input(bytes), classOf[java.util.Collection[AnyRef]]).toList
```

or

```
listSerializer.read(kryo, new Input(bytes), classOf[ListBuffer[AnyRef]]).toList
```

but nothing I tried compiles.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use Chill or akka-kryo-serialization, linked from the Kryo docs.